# Display bootstrap modal on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, mobile, responsive, ng-bootstrap

I have created a modal to warn mobile users to turn on their WIFI before proceeding through my data-intensive site. I would like to open this modal on mobile (xs, s) devices. I am using bootstrap 4.

I have tried to leverage the bootstrap [responsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) in my template, particularly the class `.hidden-md-up`, but no matter where I use this class, there ends up some remaining overlay that disables some site functionality. This is because I'm still opening the modal, then hiding it: not an elegant solution.

**I'm looking for any way to leverage bootstrap to sense for a small screen / mobile device.** I'm using angular 2, and therefore am avoiding jQuery. I haven't used jQuery in my project yet. It would be nice to avoid loading the library just for this bonus functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matchmedia as below, but it relies on hard coding the width that bootstrap changes at

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    //load your modal here
} else {
    //...
}
```

If you don't want to hard code the width, check out this post for a way to determine the bootstrap size breaks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373319/4553162

Comment: You did it! I just dove into hours of hacking @media queries, with no prevail. Should have checked back here sooner :) but at least I learned. Your solution is appreciated